# Load data from server to recyclerview & cardview

Tags: php, android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I follow this tutorial but I get some problem (https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/) . I have a table named `images` with columns `id` and `images`.

This is my getData.php:

```
<?php 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $result = array(); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        array_push($result,array(
        'name'=>$row['name'],
        'url'=>$row['image']
        ));
    }

    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);
```

This is my config.java

```
package com.example.mdesigntemp;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
public class ConfigChildItem {
public static String[] names;
public static String[] urls;
public static Bitmap[] bitmaps;

public static final String GET_URL = "http://www.kinandayu.com/image_content/getAllImage.php";
public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "url";
public static final String TAG_IMAGE_NAME = "name";
public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";

public ConfigChildItem(int i){
    names = new String[i];
    urls = new String[i];
    bitmaps = new Bitmap[i];
    }
}
```

The logcat is say nothing but I get forcestop when I open my activity, can anybody give a solution, thanks in advance for all answers

Comment: Have you check your php can return result correctly? Maybe you should post your table structure in here too.

Comment: @Alex yes i do, thanks for your answer. i have solve this issue but i got new one :(

Answer (score 0):

Please add more info to your question, we don't know what you doing or how you doing it to lead to the forcestop.

1. if its an activity issue please look at your manifest and make sure you added all your activities to it.
2. Please update the question and give more info and share your log

Comment: its solved, i have 3 items in recyleradapter but i only have 2 items in my layout xml, thanks for your answer

Comment: but now i get new issue. my recylerview is not show all image from my server :(